# Incorrect output value during using 'os.path.ismount'. Python 3.7

Tags: python, macos, mount

I use the following script to check if the disk mounted:

```
import os.path

if(os.path.ismount('/Volumes/Google\ Chrome/')):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

I receive False, but the disk mounted and opened.

What is my mistake?

Comment: The path is `/Volumes/Google Chrome/`. The backslash before the space is a shell requirement, Python does not need it.

Comment: Thank you! It is strange, because I didn't receive problems with it before.
Thank you again!!!